# apply with subset function (or custom function based on subset)

Tags: r

I am trying to find a way to use `apply` function along with `subset` (or custom function based on `subset`). I know similar questions has already been asked, mine is little bit more specific. I need to subset certain part of multiple data sets based on more than one variables. I have couple "types" of data frame structures, one of them looks similar to this:

```
colour  shade   value
RED LIGHT   -1.05
RED LIGHT   -1.37
RED LIGHT   -0.32
RED LIGHT   0.87
RED LIGHT   -0.2
RED DARK    0.52
RED DARK    -0.2
RED DARK    0.64
RED DARK    1.12
RED DARK    4
BLUE    LIGHT   0.93
BLUE    LIGHT   0.78
BLUE    LIGHT   -1.84
BLUE    LIGHT   -0.5
BLUE    LIGHT   -1.11
BLUE    DARK    -4.86
BLUE    DARK    1.11
BLUE    DARK    0.14
BLUE    DARK    0.12
BLUE    DARK    -1.65
GREEN   LIGHT     3.13
GREEN   LIGHT   2.65
GREEN   LIGHT   -2.36
GREEN   LIGHT   -3.11
GREEN   LIGHT   3.49
GREEN   DARK    1.91
GREEN   DARK    -1.1
GREEN   DARK    -1.93
GREEN   DARK    1
GREEN   DARK    -0.23
```

I have  lot of those. They names are stored in

`list.dfs.names=df1,df2,df3`

Based on this I need to use `subset` or custom function based on it:

`customSubset=function(df,col,shade){subset(df,df$colour %in% col & df$shade %in% shade)}`

I use custom functions like this because as I said I have couple types of df structures and it speeds up my work a little bit. It works like this:

`example=customSubset(df1,"BLUE","DARK")`

and output is:

```
   colour shade value
11   BLUE LIGHT  0.93
12   BLUE LIGHT  0.78
13   BLUE LIGHT -1.84
14   BLUE LIGHT -0.50
15   BLUE LIGHT -1.11
16   BLUE  DARK -4.86
17   BLUE  DARK  1.11
18   BLUE  DARK  0.14
19   BLUE  DARK  0.12
20   BLUE  DARK -1.65
```

Till now I was using `for` loops but I want to change my approach to `apply` which seems to be more convenient especially where  nesting loops is required. So  I tired:

`lapply(customSubset(list.dfs.names, "BLUE","DARK") )`

and

`lapply(list.dfs.names, customSubset("BLUE","DARK") )`

with no success. Could anyone give mi little hand on this issue, I dont think I clearly understand how `apply` loops works. However I am quite familiar with `for` method so any additional explanation about differences would be appreciated.

If it is not possible with `customSubset`  its ok for me to use regular `subset` or any other method that  produces same result as `example` presented above.

Thank you in advance

EDIT: here is code to produce similar df to example i posted:

```
`data.frame("colour"=(c(rep("RED",10),rep("BLUE",10),rep("GREEN",10)))
           ,"shade"=c(rep(c(rep("LIGHT",5),rep("DARK",5)),3))
           , runif(30,min=0,max=1))`
```

EDIT2:As requested I am editing my post to expand it on my `year` problem. My dfs comes from different years (multiple from each) for example like this: `df.1.2012`, `df.2.2012`,`df.1.2011` and so on. The main issue is that I never need to refer to same year in all of dfs (it would be very easy then) instead I need to subset data based on certain horizon (example: `year+2` or `year-1`). I used to create list of desired years (example with `year+2` it would be `list.year=c(2014,2014,2013)`) which was paired with list of my dfs (that how it worked with `for loop`).

I need to find similar method for `apply` approach. Here is example:

```
set.seed(200)

 df_2014=data.frame(colour=(c(rep("RED",10),rep("BLUE",10),rep("GREEN",10)))
           ,shade=c(rep(c(rep("LIGHT",5),rep("DARK",5)),3))
           ,year=c(rep(2011:2015,6))
           ,value=runif(30,min=0,max=1))

 df_2013=data.frame(colour=(c(rep("RED",10),rep("BLUE",10),rep("GREEN",10)))
           ,shade=c(rep(c(rep("LIGHT",5),rep("DARK",5)),3))
           ,year=c(rep(2011:2015,6))
           ,value=runif(30,min=0,max=1))
horizon=+1

subset(df_2014, df_2014$colour %in% "BLUE" & df_2014$shade %in% "DARK" & df_2014$year %in% c(2014+horizon))
subset(df_2013, df_2013$colour %in% "BLUE" & df_2013$shade %in% "DARK" & df_2013$year %in% c(2013+horizon))
```

So i added column with years and i called it `year` and named dfs after year (so `year+1` would be here `2014+1`). Horizon is self explanatory. Result is:

```
#df_2014
      colour shade year   value
 20   BLUE  DARK 2015 0.6463296

#df_2013

   colour shade year     value
20   BLUE  DARK 2015 0.6532767
```

I need to use `apply` function to list of data frames (in this edit `list.df=list(df_2014,df_2013)` as in previous example but this time add subset condition `year+horizon` (and possible puts all result in one df, but this is not main issue here).

In conclusion: when you look at both my `subset` function in this part in `year+horizon`, `year` has to change based on which df(from list) in loop it refers (while `horizon` is constant).

If you have trouble understanding what I mean please let me know, I tried to be very specific.

Comment: Put all the data frames in a list and use `lapply(list, function(x) {return(customSubset(x, "BLUE","DARK"))})`

Comment: It returned me error: `Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors `. What I did wrong?

Comment: assuming df1 is the data.frame posted in the OP and df2 is a similar data.frame :`lapply(list(df1, df2), function(x) {return(customSubset(x, "BLUE","DARK"))})` should work.

Comment: `dplyr::filter` with `purrr::map` could also be tried!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be the construct

```
subset(df,df$colour %in% col & df$shade %in% shade)
```

You are using `subset`, that evaluates the logical expression in the environment of its first argument, `df`, and then doing `df$shade %in% shade`. This is equivalent to `shade %in% shade`, since the `df` is the first argument. You should rewrite the function as follows, to use different names will do the trick.

```
customSubset <- function(DF, COL, SHADE){
    subset(DF, colour %in% COL & shade %in% SHADE)
}
```

Now everything works as expected.

```
set.seed(5601)    # make the results reproducible

df1 <- data.frame(colour = sample(c("RED", "GREEN", "BLUE"), 30, TRUE),
                  shade = sample(c("LIGHT", "DARK"), 30, TRUE),
                  value = rnorm(30, sd = 9))
df2 <- data.frame(colour = c(rep("RED",10), rep("BLUE",10), rep("GREEN",10))
           ,shade=c(rep(c(rep("LIGHT",5),rep("DARK",5)), 3))
           , value = runif(30,min=0,max=1))

list.dfs <- list(df1, df2)

customSubset(df1,"BLUE","DARK")
#   colour shade      value
#5    BLUE  DARK   4.288107
#6    BLUE  DARK   2.860724
#8    BLUE  DARK -10.720379
#10   BLUE  DARK -15.407090
#14   BLUE  DARK  -2.259848
#30   BLUE  DARK -18.364494

# apply the function to all df's in the list
# both forms are equivalent
lapply(list.dfs, function(x) customSubset(x, "BLUE", "DARK"))
lapply(list.dfs, customSubset, "BLUE", "DARK")
```

Comment: Thank you very much that works perfectly, however i have one simple problem while applying it to my original code: one of variable is numeric (year to be more specific). So i tried something like this `list.year=c(2015,2015,2016,2016)` (for four dfs) with one of your code `lapply(list.dfs, customSubset, "BLUE", "DARK", list.year[i])`. I used `[i]` in similar way like in `for` method which means i assign year (or multiple years) for each df and  subset data. How this work with `apply` approach?

Comment: Now the question is different, function `customSubset` would have an extra argument `year`. Can you please edit the question and give us an example of the expected output?

Comment: I edidet my post. Please let me know if something is unclear.